# Merge nodes with XSL v.1.0 based on a substring of an Attribute

Tags: xslt, wix, gac, heat

I have an XML file generated with heat.exe from wix-toolset. That wraps each `<File>` object inside a `<Component>`. 
I have to modify this with an XSLT v1.0, so that all `<File>` where `@Source` contains the same FileName (without extension) should be extracted to one `<Component>`. Usually, `@Source` only ends with ".dll" or ".config".

Additional the `<File>`s ending with:

- ".config" should set the `@KeyPath` to "no"
- ".dll" should have an extra attribute `@Assembly` with value ".net"

Here is a sample XML I which has to be transformed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="GAC35">
        <Component Id="cmp5BC59A7DCA65D1B974894AAA758DB693" Guid="{1A2AC82E-7AD9-4CB6-BF42-4D31FAD7786E}">
            <File Id="filE7FFE881A5ECF045432F46FBA78AEDD4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.1.0.Logging.config" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp7F80B805A2BDCF92241FB8019B91FF1C" Guid="{0F88D7E9-355A-40C1-AC8C-29BBB27690FB}">
            <File Id="filB35F1D68CCC038864F21E76D8A9F5977" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.1.0.Logging.dll" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="test1" Guid="{1A2AC82E-7AD9-4CB6-BF42-4D31FAD7786E}">
            <File Id="filE7FFE881A5ECF045432F46FBA78AEDD4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.2.0.Logging.config" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="test12" Guid="{0F88D7E9-355A-40C1-AC8C-29BBB27690FB}">
            <File Id="filB35F1D68CCC038864F21E76D8A9F5977" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.2.0.Logging.dll" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="HeatGenerated_Gac35Policies">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp5BC59A7DCA65D1B974894AAA758DB693" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp7F80B805A2BDCF92241FB8019B91FF1C" />
        <ComponentRef Id="test1" />
        <ComponentRef Id="test2" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Then this should be the expected ouput with XSL v1:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="GAC35">
     <Component Id="cmp5BC59A7DCA65D1B974894AAA758DB693"
                Guid="{1A2AC82E-7AD9-4CB6-BF42-4D31FAD7786E}">
        <File Id="filE7FFE881A5ECF045432F46FBA78AEDD4"
              KeyPath="no"
              Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.1.0.Logging.config"/>
        <File Id="filB35F1D68CCC038864F21E76D8A9F5977"
              KeyPath="yes"
              Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.1.0.Logging.dll"
              Assembly=".net"/>
     </Component>
     <Component Id="test1"
                Guid="guid1">
        <File Id="filE7FFE881A5ECF045432F46FBA78AEDD4"
              KeyPath="no"
              Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.2.0.Logging.config"/>
        <File Id="filB35F1D68CCC038864F21E76D8A9F5977"
              KeyPath="yes"
              Source="$(var.HarvestLoggingGac35Policy)\Policy.2.0.Logging.dll"
              Assembly=".net"/>
     </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="HeatGenerated_Gac35Policies">
     <ComponentRef Id="cmp5BC59A7DCA65D1B974894AAA758DB693"/>
     <ComponentRef Id="test1"/>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**EDIT**: This was my own last "solution" (not complete) until I have used the answer from @michael.hor257k

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
<xsl:output method="xml"
          indent="yes"
          omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="wix:Component">

<xsl:variable name="fileExtension">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(wix:File/@Source, '.config')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.config'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(wix:File/@Source, '.dll')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.dll'"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="precedingFileExtension">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(preceding-sibling::wix:Component/wix:File/@Source, '.config')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.config'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(preceding-sibling::wix:Component/wix:File/@Source, '.dll')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.dll'"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="wix:File[(substring-before(substring-after(@Source,'\'), $fileExtension) = substring-before(substring-after(preceding::wix:Component/wix:File/@Source,'\'), $precedingFileExtension))]" mode="files"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="wix:File" mode="files">

<xsl:variable name="fileExtension">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(@Source, '.config')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.config'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(@Source, '.dll')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.dll'"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="otherFileExtension">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(@Source, '.config')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.dll'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(@Source, '.dll')">
      <xsl:value-of select="'.config'"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<Component>
  <xsl:copy-of select="parent::wix:Component/@*" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:variable name="source" select="substring-before(substring-after(@Source,'\'), $fileExtension)"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="//wix:File[substring-before(substring-after(@Source,'\'), $otherFileExtension)=$source]" />
</Component>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:key name="policy-config-file"
         match="wix:File[contains(@Source, '.config')]"
         use="@Id" />

<xsl:template match="wix:File[key('policy-config-file', @Id)]" >
  <xsl:element name="File">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">
      <xsl:value-of select="'no'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. Please explain the problem **in words**, possibly reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. -- P.S. What exactly is the point of  `*[self::wix:File]`? How is that different from `wix:File`?

Comment: I require an XSL file where the output gets all <File> objects with the same File Name (without extension) under the same <Component>. I have tried also Muenchian Grouping with a substring of @Source but without success.

Comment: Well, then why don't you reduce the example to that? -- . Hint: you will have to do this in two steps: (1) extract the file name; (2) Muenchian grouping. Which XSLT processor will you be using? You could use some help from extension functions here.

Comment: I am using it inside Visual Studio and this should use XSLT processor v1. I have tried to extract only the filename with substring methods, but since they have to be dynamic I am not able to use the key() function anymore which is required for the grouping. I have dynamically cut off the extension at the end with a <when> tag, Could you may provide a working XSLT which extracts the filename and groups them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot group nodes by something they do not have. If you want to group the components by their filename without the extension, you must start by adding such value to each component - either as an element or as an attribute. This is because removing the extension is not trivial in XSLT 1.0 and cannot be accomplished by a single XPath expression.

Once you have done that, you can proceed and apply Muenchian grouping to the interim result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="wix:Component" use="key"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="components">
        <xsl:for-each select="wix:Component">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
                <key>
                    <xsl:call-template name="remove-last-token">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="wix:File/@Source"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </key>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($components)/wix:Component[count(. | key('k', key)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k', key)/wix:File"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-last-token">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-last-token">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG9

---

### Addendum:

If you can safely assume that the extension will always be either  `.dll` or `.config`, then you could simplify this to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="wix:Component" use="substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(wix:File/@Source, '.dll'), '.dll'), '.config'), '.config')"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="wix:Component[count(. | key('k', substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(wix:File/@Source, '.dll'), '.dll'), '.config'), '.config'))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k', substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(wix:File/@Source, '.dll'), '.dll'), '.config'), '.config'))/wix:File"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```